# Serialization of function with global variable

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I am trying to serialize a function using `dill` which contains a global variable. I am getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

```
import dill
import base64
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import cv2
import imutils

args ={
    "prototxt": "MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt",
    "model": "MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel",
    "confidence":0.2
}
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
def detect(frame):
    f1 = imutils.resize(frame,width=500)
    global net
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(f1,(300,300)), 0.007843,(300,300), 127.5 )
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()
    return detections
s = base64.b64encode(dill.dumps(detect,recurse=True))
print(s)
```

and in another file it receives the searialized version of the function which is the output of the first function

```
import dill
import base64
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import cv2
import imutils
args ={
    "prototxt": "MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt",
    "model": "MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel",
    "confidence":0.2
}
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

b = # searialized function string
f = base64.b64decode(b)
func = dill.loads(f)
frame = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
print(func(frame))
```

the environment, libraries are all set up on both the systems are identical. After debugging the code I found out that the variable `net` is not present in the function created after deseialization

What is a possible way to serialize this?

**Update:** Running the fault handler gave this output

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f4147647700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/sandeep/Huawei/real-time-object-detection/migration_test1.py", line 17 in detect
  File "migration_test2.py", line 17 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

line 17 in migration_test1.py represents the `line net.setInput(blob)`
line 17 in migration_test2.py represents the `line print(func(frame))`
```

Comment: You only need `global` if you are going to assign directly to the name. Here, you are just using two of its methods; `net` is a free variable that normal name lookup will find in an enclosing scope, so you can drop `global net` completely.

Comment: even without `global` it did not work as `net` is defined outside the scope of the function. If I define it inside the function it is working but I don't want to define it inside the function as it might define the same object multiple times whenever the function gets called

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  You start by saying you are getting a `SegmentationFault`.  My inclination is to have you `dump` both `net` and `detect`, then `load` both of them into the new python session.  However, if you are getting a `SegmentationFault` it's probably because you are trying to serialize something that requires a C library.  Seeing you traceback would help.  Either posted here or on the `dill` GitHub issues page.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns how can I get the traceback. As soon as I run the code I am getting `Segmentation Fault` When I use the debugger provided by `VSCode` I see that the variable `net` is not present while it is executing the function

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/faulthandler.html

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I updated the question after running `faulthandler`